# Remote MySQL Server connection w/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, remote-server

I need to connect to an external MySQL database and fetch some data. I have a few concerns about it:

1. Connecting to a remote server will increase the loading time of the page, I want that to be the lowest as possible.
2. The data I need to load is extra, if the remote server appears to be down I don't want to wait extra time (until it times out).

What are the best practices on connecting to a remote MySQL database using PHP? Basically, I want my website loading time to be affected as smallest as possible.

If it can't be done with PHP, I'm open to a different approach.

Comment: Define "external"? How far away is this server?

Comment: Two different servers, two different hosting companies. Both in America but it might change.

Comment: That's a big country. New York to California can introduce serious latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, build an API for one end which has local access to the database, and an API consumer at your remote. Then you can institute a time-out on the API fetch call. Writing a simple JSON-type wrapper around a database is not usually that difficult.

The alternatives are messy, such as a VPN, an SSH bridge, or remote access to the MySQL port using SSL/TLS for encryption. The database driver will struggle when you have an unreliable connection, or one that suffers packet loss. Performance will be erratic at best.

Comment: I've already considered this solution. On Server A I would create a JSONP API which will be called by Server B through a jQuery's $.getJSON. If there is no better answer I will select yours as accepted, thanks!

Comment: I've found this approach to be the most reliable since each API call is an independent request. If one fails, it's no big deal. On the other hand, maintaining persistent database connections can be a nuisance, and if one fails, it will produce all kinds of errors within your application.

Answer (score 0):

You might try MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT option for [mysqli_real_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php). It has had some quirks though, check [this](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2009/phpc-does-mysqli_opt_connect_timeout-work/) out.

That said, I concur with @tadman, building a server API is probably the best option. Synchronous calls to unreachable remote servers will render your own service unusable for all practical purposes.